# Numpy vectorization: Find intersection between list and list of lists

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to find the intersection between a list and a list of lists. This is trivially solved with a simple for loop:

```
def find_intersec(x,y):
    result = []

    for i in range(len(y)):
        if set(x).intersection(set(y[i])):
            result.append(y[i])

    return(result)

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [9,10,11]]



find_intersec(x,y)
```

How can I change the above into a numpy vectorization solution? I have tried `numpy.intersect1d()` with no success.

Comment: Can we assume `y` to have same number of elements across all inner lists, which is `3` in the posted sample?

Comment: No, `y` has a variable number of elements across inner lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a function like this:

```
import numpy as np

def find_intersec_vec(x, y):
    y_all = np.concatenate(y)
    y_all_in = np.isin(y_all, x)
    splits = np.cumsum([0] + [len(lst) for lst in y])
    y_in = np.logical_or.reduceat(y_all_in, splits[:-1])
    return [lst for lst, isin in zip(y, y_in) if isin]
```

Test:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
print(find_intersec(x, y))
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
print(find_intersec_vec(x, y))
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, `numpy.intersect1d()` can be used:

```
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [9,10,11]]

intersec = [np.intersect1d(i, x) for i in y if len(np.intersect1d(i, x)) > 0]
```

result:

```
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]
```