# Length of the intersections between a list an list of list

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, set-intersection

Note : almost duplicate of [Numpy vectorization: Find intersection between list and list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394093/numpy-vectorization-find-intersection-between-list-and-list-of-lists)

Differences :

- I am focused on efficiently when the lists are large
- I'm searching for the largest intersections.

```
x = [500 numbers between 1 and N]
y = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12], etc. up to N]
```

Here are some assumptions:

- `y` is a list of ~500,000 sublist of ~500 elements
- each sublist in `y` is a range, so `y` is characterized by the last elements of each sublists. In the example : 3, 7, 9, 12 ...
- `x` is not sorted
- `y` contains once and only once each numbers between 1 and ~500000*500
- `y` is sorted in the sense that, as in the example, the sub-lists are sorted and the first element of one sublist is the next of the last element of the previous list.
- `y` is known long before even compile-time

My purpose is to know, among the sublists of `y`, which have at least 10 intersections with `x`.

I can obviously make a loop :

```
def find_best(x, y):
    result = []

    for index, sublist in enumerate(y):
        intersection = set(x).intersection(set(sublist))
        if len(intersection) > 2:  # in real live: > 10
            result.append(index)

    return(result)


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [[1, 2, 3], [4],  [5, 6], [7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]

res = find_best(x, y)
print(res)   # [0, 2]
```

Here the result is `[0,2]` because the first and third sublist of `y` have 2 elements in intersection with `x`.

An other method should to parse only once `y` and count the intesections :

```
def find_intersec2(x, y):
    n_sublists = len(y)
    res = {num: 0 for num in range(0, n_sublists + 1)}
    for list_no, sublist in enumerate(y):
        for num in sublist:
            if num in x:
                x.remove(num)
                res[list_no] += 1
    return [n for n in range(n_sublists + 1) if res[n] >= 2]
```

This second method uses more the hypothesis.

Questions :

- what optimizations are possibles ?
- Is there a completely different approach ? Indexing, kdtree ? In my use case, the large list `y` is known days before the actual run. So i'm not afraid to buildind an index or whatever from `y`. The small list `x` is only known at runtime.

Comment: Few questions: What is the average size of items in the `y` list and what is the biggest one? Are the items of sublists in `y` always a range of integer without holes or this is just the case for the example? You said "at least 10 intersections" but the threshold is set to 2 in the code, so is it normal?

Comment: I edited the question to answer. In short : yes the sublists in y are ranges, the largest element is around 500,000 * 500. I set threshold = 2 in the example, to show the principle on a short data. In real live : 10.

Comment: Note that `find_best` should use `>=2` instead of `>2` to get the result provided in the answer and match with the description of the wanted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `y` contains *disjoint ranges* and the union of them is also a range, a very fast solution is to first perform a binary search on `y` and then count the resulting indices and only return the ones that appear at least 10 times. The complexity of this algorithm is `O(Nx log Ny)` with `Nx` and `Ny` the number of items in respectively `x` and `y`. This algorithm is *nearly optimal* (since `x` needs to be read entirely).

---

### Actual implementation

First of all, you need to transform your current `y` to a Numpy array containing the beginning value of all ranges (in an increasing order) with `N` as the last value (assuming `N` is excluded for the ranges of `y`, or `N+1` otherwise). This part can be assumed as free since `y` can be computed at compile time in your case. Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
y = np.array([1, 4, 8, 10, 13, ..., N])
```

Then, you need to perform the binary search and check that the values fits in the range of y:

```py
indices = np.searchsorted(y, x, 'right')

# The `0 < indices < len(y)` check should not be needed regarding the input.
# If so, you can use only `indices -= 1`.
indices = indices[(0 < indices) & (indices < len(y))] - 1
```

Then you need to count the indices and filter the ones with at least :

```py
uniqueIndices, counts = np.unique(indices, return_counts=True)
result = uniqueIndices[counts >= 10]
```

Here is an example based on your:

```py
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

# [[1, 2, 3], [4],  [5, 6], [7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
y = np.array([1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 12])

# Actual simplified version of the above algorithm
indices = np.searchsorted(y, x, 'right') - 1
uniqueIndices, counts = np.unique(indices, return_counts=True)
result = uniqueIndices[counts >= 2]

# [0, 2]
print(result.tolist())
```

It runs in less than 0.1 ms on my machine on a random input based on your input constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Turn y into 2 dicts.

```
index = { # index to count map
    0 : 0,
    1 : 0,
    2 : 0,
    3 : 0,
    4 : 0
}

y = { # elem to index map
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 1,
    5: 2,
    6: 2,
    7: 3,
    8 : 4,
    9 : 4,
    10 : 4,
    11 : 4
}
```

Since you know `y` in advance, I don't count the above operations into the time complexity. Then, to count the intersection:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for e in x: index[y[e]] += 1
```

Since you mentioned `x` is small, I try to make the time complexity depends only on the size of `x` (in this case `O(n)`).

Finally, the answer is the list of keys in index dict where the value is >= 2 (or 10 in real case).

```
answer = [i for i in index if index[i] >= 2]
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is it requires to build a *huge* dict that will certainly not fit in RAM and very slow to create/allocate. Indeed, `N ~= 500000*500 ~= 250_000_000` and so this means `index` contains 250 million of items. On a 64-bit architecture, CPython needs to store 2 references of 8 bytes for each item of `index` and the each of the two reference refer to allocated integer objects of 32 bytes. This means at least `2*(32+8)*250_000_000 ~= 18.6 GiB` of RAM! Actually, on my machine this takes about 28 GiB of RAM (since hash tables needs some additional space due to collisions).

Comment: Yup. Actually `index` only contains `500,000` items, but you are right the `y` dict contains `250,000,000` items. It is always a trade-off between memory vs performance. Also my understanding `int` is 32 bits instead of bytes, no? So the order of RAM is < 10 GiB. I actually tried to initialize y `for i in range(250000000): y[i] = 0`, took 2GB. How did you get 28GB? Anyway this the "build index" approach, which OP specifically mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, I meant `y` and not `index` (it was `index` before the question was edited ;) ). Note that CPython integers are not directly native ones. The interpreter stores each integers in a separate CPython object (`PyVarObject` type). Unfortunately, such objects have a pretty big overhead since the interpreter stores the type of the object as a 64-bit pointer, a 32-byte integer value (for small ones), a 64-bit integer size, a 64-bit counter (so the reference counting can delete the object when it is not used anymore). Compilers usually add some padding too so the structure is aligned in memory.

Comment: I tried with `tmp = {i: i+1 for i in range(250_000_000)}`, but your code takes 20 GiB on my machine. Did you missed a 0? Note that CPython can make some basic optimizations so not to allocates objects. For example, when you do `y[i] = 0` or `y[i] = i+1`, the memory overhead is not the same since it only allocates one integer `0` for all the values in the first case and 250 million integers for all the values in the second case (hence the ~8 GiB additional memory usage). 250 million integer keys are allocated anyway.

Comment: Note that you can find the definition of the `PyObject`/`PyVarObject` structure [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/70c16468deee9390e34322d32fda57df6e0f46bb/Include/object.h#L115) and the one of (variable-sized) integers [there](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/70c16468deee9390e34322d32fda57df6e0f46bb/Include/cpython/longintrepr.h#L79) (based on `PyVarObject`).

Comment: Ok I'm not sure how the data structure memory implementation is. But to summarize, I think the key point is that it is a trade-off: with a full blown dict, the complexity is O(Nx). But as you pointed out this needs memory. If the memory is a constraint, you can reduce the index size using a sorted list instead. But the complexity becomes O(Nx log Ny). Both options are valid, depending on system constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `y` to create a linear array mapping every int to the (1 plus), the index of the range or subgroup the int is in; called `x2range_counter`.

`x2range_counter` uses a 32 bit array.array type to save memory and can be cached and used for calculations of **all** `x` on the same `y`.

calculating the hits in each range for a particular `x` is then just indirected array incrementing of a `count'er in function` count_ranges`.

```
y = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
x = [5, 3, 1, 11, 8, 10]

range_counter_max = len(y)
extent = y[-1][-1] + 1  # min in y must be 1 not 0 remember.
x2range_counter = array.array('L', [0] * extent)  # efficient 32 bit array storage

# Map any int in any x to appropriate ranges counter.
for range_counter_index, rng in enumerate(y, start=1):
    for n in rng:
        x2range_counter[n] = range_counter_index
print(x2range_counter)  # array('L', [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])

# x2range_counter can be saved for this y and any x on this y.

def count_ranges(x: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    "Number of x-hits on each y subgroup in order"
    # Note: count[0] initially catches errors. count[1..] counts x's in y ranges [0..]
    count = array.array('L', [0] * (range_counter_max + 1))
    for xx in x:
        count[x2range_counter[xx]] += 1
    assert count[0] == 0, "x values must all exist in a y range and y must have all int in its range."

    return count[1:] 

print(count_ranges(x))  # array('L', [1, 2, 1, 2])
```

I created a class for this, with extra functionality such as returning the ranges rather than the indices; all ranges hit >=M times; (range, hit-count) tuples sorted most hit first.

Range calculations for different x are proportional to x and are simple array lookups rather than any hashing of dicts.

What do you think?

Comment: The output is not the one expected by the OP: your code gives `[3, 1, 2, 0, 0]` for the example of the OP while it should be `[0, 2]`. A filtering step is needed to get the result. The complexity of the approach is `O(Ny + Nx)` assuming `x2range_counter` is already created ahead of time (which is much bigger than `O(Nx)` or `O(Nx log Ny)`). Additionally, `x2range_counter` takes about 1 GiB in RAM which is quite big although most PC can hold this and this is significantly less than the solution of Register Sole (but >250~500 times more than mine).

Comment: Hi Jerome, please check your reasons as, after any data structure construction on y, that the author says can be ignored as there are many x lookups for the y; your solution needs a binary search for every member of x versus one indirected array lookup which should be constant for every member of x, and quick.

Comment: On memory Jerome, after y is transformed, the original y could be deleted or changed to an array of just the highs of each sublist to allow all ranges to be recreated.

Comment: `y` can bee indeed ignored, but `x2range_counter` cannot: it needs to be loaded somewhere (typically in RAM so that your algorithm can be fast) during the execution of the algorithm and this variable is the big one.

Comment: I agree for the binary search, but note that Numpy is highly-optimized (written in C), and in the end, the binary search of each value is faster than one direct access of `x2range_counter`. One reason is that the `y` in my code can fit in the (low-latency) CPU cache and `log(Ny) ~= 20` so `Nx log (Ny) ~= 10_000` while `Ny ~= 500_000` (`count` must be written/read). Moreover, the loop of your code is interpreted which is slow. Additionally, unpredictable access in RAM are very expensive (especially when interpreted: 50~100 ns/access) and `x2range_counter` is too big to fit in CPU caches.

Comment: I think your code could be very fast if it would be written in a native language (like C/C++) or optimized with Numba/Cython, if `count` would be an optimized hash-map (with open-addressing) and if accesses to `x2range_counter` are prefetched manually using low-level prefetch instructions. I think it may be faster than the in-cache binary search (hard to say due to the high cost of RAM accesses). The memory impact is still big. I guess this is the trade-off to pay.

Comment: Again, a single indirected array lookup will be faster than any hash maps hashing algorithm. There might me a single assembly instruction to do the indirected summation, but I prefer to leave straight Python answers to Python questions if I can, as I find Python most enjoyable.

Comment: A small highly-optimized hashmap implementation can be actually faster than a direct access to a big array that does not fit in the L1/L2 cache and often does. On my 4.5GHz Intel Skylake processor for example le L1 latency is of 3 cycles, 10c for the L2, and 30-60c for the L3 and 30-100 ns for the RAM. The time to compute a highly-optimized hash function is of few cycles and it can be computed in parallel thanks to ILP and OOO execution. The hashmap indirect access in the L1 cache will only cost 3 cycles and 2 load/cycle can be done in parallel. Memory accesses matter more than computation!

Comment: As for the number of instruction, it is clearly not a good metric for speed. 1 div instruction can takes dozens of cycles while 4 integer add/sub instructions can be computed in parallel on modern x86-64 processors (eg. Intel Skylake/IceLake & AMD Zen2). The RDTSCP instruction can even takes about 30-50 ns. For more informations, you can read [this](https://www.gwern.net/docs/cs/2007-drepper.pdf) and [this](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/istc/istc.html). [Here](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16084/intel-tiger-lake-review-deep-dive-core-11th-gen/4) is an bench showing memory latencies.

Comment: I guess it would take real code, real examples, real hardware.